# WinForms Aero Wizard in C#?

Tags: c#, winforms, wizard, aero

I'm looking to implement a wizard C# in WinForms (*not* WPF), and I'd like it to comply with the Aero Wizard guidelines.

Can anyone point me at some sample code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two projects on Codeplex:

- [AeroGlassProvider](http://aeroglassprovider.codeplex.com/)
- [Windows Forms Aero](http://windowsformsaero.codeplex.com/)

The first was started in Feb 2009, the second in Feb 2007 (it has screen shots which seem to indicate it works), but neither have been updated recently.

Comment: I wrote the AeroGlassProvider. There are screenshots in the .chm file although I didn't take the time to place them into the Codeplex main screen. AeroGlassProvider may help create the Aero Wizard but it does not purport to follow the Aero Wizard guidelines.

Comment: @mreith - Thanks for the info, I didn't have time to check these out in great detail.

Answer (score -1):

There is an Aero Wizard Demo in the Windows SDK .NET Framework 3.0 Samples. Download it [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=22b58b6c-8f98-40d0-880d-c3339c5da01e&displaylang=en&Hash=o28EB4dRxcgRCti2ezvGg%2fsGk%2bZKcCYDbdL5zH3FOSKhvlZhK%2bGittfYhWfYlQk4mOhGbE2pUaebMslDX7vtDA%3d%3d)

Comment: There is a Windows Forms sample in that download.

Comment: (coming back to this) Where in that download? All I can find is WPF examples.