# Using aero theme in Winforms like we do in WPF

Tags: c#, winforms, themes, aero

I know how to use the Aero theme in my wpf applications when running in Windows XP.[Link](http://dvuyka.spaces.live.com/blog/cns!305B02907E9BE19A!199.entry)

Is there any way to do the same in a Winforms application?

Thanks.

Comment: A duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136043/winforms-aero-wizard-in-c - but that's not answered either

Comment: I've added an answer to that question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1136043/winforms-aero-wizard-in-c/1735703#1735703

Answer (score 0):

[http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-*1320*-Part-1-*1320*-Aero-Wizards](http://weblogs.asp.net/kennykerr/Windows-Vista-for-Developers-_1320_-Part-1-_1320_-Aero-Wizards)